# How to Extract the Tag name from ec2 snapshot_id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

With this command I am getting the snapshot id but i want to get the name associated with this id [TAGS]

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids **********  --output text | awk /vol-6ac16d63/ | grep -y "2014-02-01" | awk "/vol-6ac16d63/{print \$5}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [describe-tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html):

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters Name=resource-id,Values=snap-XXXXXXX Name=key,Values=Name --query "Tags[*].Value" --output text
```